# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql in Kafka Connect

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

connect-standalone.properties

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
bootstrap.servers=10.33.62.20:9092,10.33.62.110:9092,10.33.62.200:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=/grid/1/mukul/confluent-5.0.0/share/java
```

source-sqlite.properties

```
name=test-source-sqlite-jdbc-autoincrement
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=5

connection.url=jdbc:mysql://10.32.177.178:3306/test&user=xxxx&password=xxxxx

table.whitelist=banner_hourly_statistics_v2

group.id=test-mysql-kafka
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

config.storage.topic=demo-1-distributed-config
offset.storage.topic=demo-1-distributed-offset
status.storage.topic=demo-1-distributed-status

bootstrap.servers=10.33.62.20:9092,10.33.62.110:9092,10.33.62.200:9092
mode=bulk
#incrementing.column.name=id
topic.prefix=test-sqlite-jdbc-
```

CMD: `connect-standalone /grid/1/mukul/confluent-5.0.0/etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties /grid/1/mukul/confluent-5.0.0/etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-quickstart-sqlite.properties`

In the startup logs, it clearly shows loading JDBC Connectors:

```
[2018-08-09 06:59:30,072] INFO Loading plugin from: /grid/1/mukul/confluent-5.0.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:218)
[2018-08-09 06:59:30,133] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/grid/1/mukul/confluent-5.0.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:241)
[2018-08-09 06:59:30,133] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:170)
[2018-08-09 06:59:30,133] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:170)
```

But it fails with following exception:

```
Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://10.32.177.178:3306/test&user=xxxx&password=xxxx for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:mysql://10.32.177.178:3306/test&user=xxxx&password=xxx
Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://10.32.177.178:3306/test&user=xxxx&password=xxxx for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:mysql://10.32.177.178:3306/test&user=xxxx&password=xxxx
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:79)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:66)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:110)
```

Tried changing the plugin directories too but it didn't work. Tried moving the confluent share/* to /usr/share/java too but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the JAR from the URL: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html
2. Place inside the Plugin dir
3. Run the connect

It will take start pulling data from MySql.

Comment: which plugin directory do you refer to? How do i identify which dir is being used?

Comment: @ValerianPereira :  You need to copy the Jar to plugin.path=share/java
 directory as mentioned in the etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties file

Comment: Or you can use plugin.path config present in etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties  file for standalone mode.

Comment: Thanks for your help @mukul I got this fixed. The JAR was placed well in share/java dir, however, i missed to restart the service, for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

May be a little late. I had the same issue of "No Driver found.." when I connect DB2 using kafka jdbc connector.

***1st Possible Solution:***

I resolved it by placing the DB2 driver at the exact location where jdbc-connector is.
With in Kafka connect:

`find / -name kafka-connect-jdbc\*.jar`

Once you found the location from the above command, copy DB2 jar at that location:

`cp {your DB2 jar location}/db2.jar {copy the location from 'find' command}`

Example

`cp /Download/db2.jar /Users/share/java/kafka-connect-java/`

Restart kafka-connect, it will pick up the DB2 drivers

***2nd Possible Solution:***

Download the jt400 jar (jdk-8) and put it next to the other jdbc drivers (DB2, SQL etc)

Happy coding :)