# Where should the MySQL driver go in Confluent Platform 6.2?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to connect to a MySQL store as a sink using the JDBC connector for Confluent 6.2 but Connect is throwing the following exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:3306/new_employees
```

I've tried placing the `mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar` in a number of different folders in the Confluent installation including `share/java` (that's listed in the SO answer referenced link below) and `share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc` (had to create that folder; based on the "Yeah, trust me" comment in https://supergloo.com/kafka-connect/kafka-connect-mysql-example/ and the confluent documentation at https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/index.html), but Confluent doesn't seem to be looking anywhere I've placed it.

I have read through the answers at [No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql in Kafka Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51758456/no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-in-kafka-connect), but that is old, and the situation seems to have changed for Confluent version 6.2.  I have also verified the connection string and credentials using VSCode.

Here is the connect configuration I'm using (edited for security purposes):

```
{
  "name": "JdbcSinkConnectorConnector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "topics": "emp.employees.departments, emp.employees.dept_emp, emp.employees.dept_manager, emp.employees.employees, emp.employees.salaries, emp.employees.titles",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:3306/new_employees",
    "connection.user": "XXXXXX",
    "connection.password": "YYYYYY",
    "dialect.name": "MySqlDatabaseDialect",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "auto.evolve": "true"
  }
}
```

So, the question is, where does Confluent look for the MySQL driver jar file for connecting to MySQL as a sink?

Comment: and none of hese suggestions with class path and so helped https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556664/how-to-fix-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dbname-error-w

Comment: @nbk There was no classpath defined earlier, but confluent seemed to be able to find other .jar files without it.  But, just to be sure, I created a classpath environment variable with the jar file listed and restarted confluent connect, resulting in no change.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Please clarify how/where you set the CLASSPATH variable and how you are running `connect-distributed` script

Comment: @OneCricketeer It was a CLASSPATH problem after all.  Not sure exactly how I messed it up initially, but it worked when I shut down and reset Confluent (`confluent local destroy`), did an `export CLASSPATH=<path to mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar>` and then started Confluent back up again (`confluent local services start`).  Is there a way to configure Confluent to include the jar without externally setting the CLASSPATH?  It seems to find the other jars just fine.

Comment: I don't use the Confluent CLI, but you can look at the `kafka-run-class` script in the Kafka bin directory to see which directories are on the default classpath, then symlink/drop your JAR there